# Assign Conditional type of interface to receive multiple api data by path-name

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

How we can assign conditional type in ReactJs typescript by follow the pathname. For example if pathname A then `interface Orders[]` if pathname B then `setState` with Locations interface so we can manage one state with multiple types of data.

```js
const [tableArray, settableArray] = useState < SingleOrder[] | LocationInterface[] | undefined | any > ();

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  if (pathname === '/bmv_location_list' && locationList) {
    settableArray(locationList);
    return setLoading(false);
  } else if (pathname === '/orders') {
    settableArray(fetchOrdersListData);
    return setLoading(false);
  } else if (pathname === '/new-orders') {
    settableArray(newOrders);
    return setLoading(false);
  }
}, [fetchOrdersListData, locationList, newOrders, pathname]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a library called React Router. You can import the `useLocation` hook like this :

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Then , you can initialize it by assigning it to a variable:

```
const location=useLocation()
```

Now you should be able to use it in the useEffect hook

Comment: i already trying out with useLocation hook and working good the problem is when we set one api data in state and assign genric type of api response then its working but when we try out 2nd api  and set response data in a same state then this will show me error we cannot assign 2nd api response because we are receiving 1st api received

Comment: @Asad I think this happens because the set function is async. Make sure the second set function runs after the first one with an arrow function , something like `prevValue =>setvalue(presentValue)`